# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function gauge.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the [gauge.js](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) plugin with my Rails 4 application, but I'm getting an **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** error in my console when trying to hit the homepage.

Here's what I have in **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require gauge.min.js
```

And here's what I have in my **index.html** view:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var opts = {
    lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
    angle: 0.15, // The length of each line
    lineWidth: 0.44, // The line thickness
    pointer: {
      length: 0.9, // The radius of the inner circle
      strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
      color: '#000000' // Fill color
    },
    limitMax: 'false',   // If true, the pointer will not go past the end of the gauge
    colorStart: '#6FADCF',   // Colors
    colorStop: '#8FC0DA',    // just experiment with them
    strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',   // to see which ones work best for you
    generateGradient: true
  };
  var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // your canvas element
  var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
  gauge.maxValue = 3000; // set max gauge value
  gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
  gauge.set(1250); // set actual value
})
</script>
```

I've searched this error and have found that it's a problem with scripts getting loaded in the wrong order, so I'm wondering if this has to do with Rails 4 turbolinks since I had an issue loading JS in other parts of my application.

Comment: I've read there are people having this problem due to importing the .min.js instead of the .js. Maybe you're facing the same issue. Can you try importing the .js instead of the .min?

Comment: Still the same issue with the .coffee version of it: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function gauge.js

Answer (score 3):

Previously I had:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**It needs to be:**

```
<canvas id="foo"></canvas>
```